# use many application bars in a pivot control

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I'm trying to create a Pivot control, and to eatch item of the Pivot control I want to assosiate a different ApplicationBar. I tried to follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394036%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) walkthrough in MSDN, but it seems to be that there is an error in this code:

```
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                ApplicationBar  = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["CountingAppBar"]);
                break;

            case 1:
                ApplicationBar  = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["SavingAppBar"]);
                break;
        }
    }
```

The error is that ApplicationBar is a class and it's used as variable, so I tried to create an instance before the switch statement, here is what I did:

```
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationBar appBar;
        switch (((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                appBar = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["CountingAppBar"]);
                break;

            case 1:
                appBar = ((ApplicationBar)Application.Current.Resources["SavingAppBar"]);
                break;
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
My level in programming is still a beginner, it would be appreciated if the answer is detailed.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you are linking to the correct page? It is for Windows Phone, and while I'm not certain, ApplicationBar might just be a inherent property of the Windows Phone application. So I'm not sure it works in WPF or Silverlight.

Comment: Might just be the fact that you're not calling the constructor, i.e. ```ApplicationBar appBar = new ApplicationBar();```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394044%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Why don't you use just one ApplicationBar and add or remove ApplicationBarButtons based on the selected Pivot control? Should be pretty straightforward considering that many apps do it.

PS: From personal experience, add your application bar via code in C#...I have faced issues while changing XAML app bars.

Comment: Fully agree on both, although of course the separation of code and UI is clearer if you use XAML for the AppBar.

Comment: Indeed....I love XAML and creating controls in it but for some reason the AppBar becomes too unpredictable in XAML and keeps on throwing NullReferenceExceptions when you try to access it in code

Answer (score 3):

**It is really simple... You can use different appbar for each pivote item. try the code below**

```
<phone:Pivot>
```

```
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger>
                <appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger.SelectionMappings>
                    <appBarUtils:SelectionMapping SourceIndex="0" TargetIndex="0"/>
                </appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger.SelectionMappings>

                <appBarUtils:SwitchAppBarAction>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="0"   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                        <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                    </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                    <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                        <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                    </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                    <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="2" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                        <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                        <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.money.png" Text="collection" Command="{Binding CollectionPageCommand}"/>
                        <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.check.rest.png" Text="ok" Command="{Binding OrderConfirmationButtonCommand}"/>
                    </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                    <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="3"  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                        <appBarUtils:AppBarButton x:Name="ConfirmationAppBarButton" IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.cancel.rest.png" Text="cancel" Command="{Binding OrderCancelButtonCommand}"/>
                        <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.check.rest.png" Text="ok" Command="{Binding OrderConfirmationButtonCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Model.EnableCheck,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                </appBarUtils:SwitchAppBarAction>
            </appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey seems to be quite late but i followed the same msdn tutorial. you may not be getting the required result as you need to attach a selection changed event with the pivot item.

```
<controls:Pivot SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged_2" >

</controls:Pivot>
```